# Is it possible in PhpStorm to use variables in macros?

Tags: macros, phpstorm

**I want to be able to create a new file for each block of code I choose.**

I have tried to record a macro (select code, create new file) and it works except that it doesn't fill the file with the selected text and I can't set a custom file name.

The code has this format

```
<div id="$name">$content</div>
```

Where $name is the name I want for the target file.

The resulting file should

- be named $named
- contain $content (ideally including the wrapping div)

Comment: No, macros don't support variables. Since you've managed to copy the name and the contents to the clipboard, it should be possible to just paste them into the appropriate fields via Paste History, did you try that?

Comment: what do you mean by "appropriate fields"? how would that automatize things?

Comment: For some reason, I thought that you somehow managed to copy `$name` and `$content` to the clipboard using a macro, and you could potentially paste them via Paste from History invoked by the same macro, but now I understand that you selected the whole piece of code instead, and want PhpStorm to parse it. I believe there's no way of achieving that, sorry for the wrong lead.